# How to apply changes to current branch or working directory by <SHA>?

Tags: git

I have commit:

```
commit 2a8da463f2ba20cbb113078f75624c35c1e198a2
Merge: e347f8c5 d5e7a67f
Author: Eugen Konkov <email>
Date:   Wed Nov 18 19:09:18 2020 +0200

    On dev: autostash
```

I try to apply this autostash commit (which is not on stash already) but get error:

```
git cherry-pick `2a8da463`
error: commit 2a8da463f2ba20cbb113078f75624c35c1e198a2 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

How to apply this commit to my branch/working directory?
(how to restore my changes from that autostash?)

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer:

```
git stash apply 2a8da46
```

from **SYNOPSIS** of `man git stash`

```
SYNOPSIS
    git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
```